# Wrong depth proportion on 3d

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a game board for 'Checkers'. I would like to rotate it a little bit on its axis (rotateX). After giving it a '120deg' rotation I noticed that the depth is disproportional. All the squares are of the same size, while the closer ones should look BIGGER the the distant ones. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/w3bow2Lc/

```js
//init board


var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var td = $('<td/>').attr('class', 'square').attr('id', counter);
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      $(td).addClass('even');
    else
      $(td).addClass('odd');
    tr.append(td);
    counter++;
  }
  $('#board').append(tr);
}

//init white soldiers
//var soldier = '<svg height="40" width="40" class="soldier" draggable="true"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="14" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" ></circle></svg>';
var soldier = '<div class="soldier white" draggable="true"></div>';
var squares = $('#board td');
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  if ($(squares[i]).hasClass('even') && i % 2 == 0)
    $(squares[i]).append($(soldier).attr('id', 'soldier' + i));
  if ($(squares[i]).hasClass('odd') && i % 2 != 0)
    $(squares[i]).append($(soldier).attr('id', 'soldier' + i));
}

//init black soldiers
//var soldier = '<svg height="40" width="40" class="soldier" draggable="true"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="14" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" ></circle></svg>';
var soldier = '<div class="soldier black" draggable="true"></div>';
var squares = $('#board td');
for (var i = 40; i < 64; i++) {
  if ($(squares[i]).hasClass('even') && i % 2 == 0)
    $(squares[i]).append($(soldier).attr('id', 'soldier' + i));
  if ($(squares[i]).hasClass('odd') && i % 2 != 0)
    $(squares[i]).append($(soldier).attr('id', 'soldier' + i));
}
```

```css
#board {
  margin: 50px 100px;
  //border:15px solid gray;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(120deg);
}

#board td {
  <!-- outline: 2px solid white;
  --> padding: 0;
}

.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid white;
}

.even:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: brown;
}

.even:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: BlanchedAlmond;
}

.odd:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: BlanchedAlmond;
}

.odd:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: brown;
}

.soldier {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='board'></table>
```

Comment: For one, you have two different comment types there(XML/HTML`<!-- -->` & JS/Others `//`), both of which are incorrect. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/comments-in-css/. `//` is valid if you are using SCSS

Comment: You are right @Jacob, but its not critical

Answer (score 1):

You need add a perspective to your parent element. In this case simply add a perspective of 800px to the body. (It would be better to wrap the board in a new element and apply the perspective to that)

```
body{
    perspective:800px;
}
```

You will also need to change your transform from `transform: rotateX(120deg);` to `transform: rotateX(-120deg);`

Working example here

https://jsfiddle.net/Jcoulterdesign/Lfwewzcn/2/

You can just tweak the perspective amount and rotation until you get the exact look you want, but this will fix the depth issue.

Comment: Actually I used the perspective (and then removed it seeing it was not working...). My mistake was that I wrote it in a new line. I wrote: ' transform: rotateX(120deg); perspective: 120px; ' I guess it can't have them both and separated. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

To define a 3d space, you need to set the `perspective` property:

```css
#board {
  margin: 50px 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(120deg);
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3bow2Lc/1/).

You can think of the value as how far away the viewer is from the object - the larger the value, the more subtle the perspective effect. Here's a [more detailed resource](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html) explaining how to use this property, and also the `perspective-origin` property. Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I used the perspective (and then removed it seeing it was not working...). My mistake was that I wrote it in a new line. I wrote:   ' transform: rotateX(120deg);
perspective: 120px; ' I guess it can't have them both and separated. Thanks for the correction.